# How do i show a value of foreign key in telerik radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, telerik

Ok I am trying to display a value of a foreign key relation ship in a telerik rad grid but I have having some isuues.

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="entPoints" Include="player" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=soccerEntities" DefaultContainerName="soccerEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="player_points" Select="it.[id], it.[playerId], it.[points], it.[pointsToRedeem], it.[dateToBeAwarded], it.[approvedBy], it.[approved], it.[authCreatedDate], it.[modifiedDate], it.[modifiedBy], it.[isActivated], it.[authUserName], it.[siteId], it.[sentApproveEmail], it.[approvedDate], it.[playerNumber], it.[playerName], it.[teamId], it.[isProcessed], it.[sentEmailToAdmin], it.[sentEmailToUser]"></asp:EntityDataSource>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grdPoints" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" RenderMode="Auto" DataSourceID="entPoints" GroupPanelPosition="Top" OnItemCommand="grdPoints_ItemCommand" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both" Skin="Bootstrap" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True">
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="entPoints" DataKeyNames="id">
<Columns>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" Visible="false" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter id column" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" UniqueName="id">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="playerName" FilterControlAltText="Filter playerName column" HeaderText="Player Name" SortExpression="playerName" UniqueName="playerName" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>

             <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="player.Name" FilterControlAltText="Filter playerName column" HeaderText="Player Name" SortExpression="playerName" UniqueName="playerName" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="playerNumber" FilterControlAltText="Filter playerNumber column" HeaderText="Player Number" SortExpression="playerNumber" UniqueName="playerNumber" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>

<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="playerId" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter playerId column" HeaderText="Player ID" SortExpression="playerId" UniqueName="playerId" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="points" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter points column" HeaderText="Points" SortExpression="points" UniqueName="points" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="pointsToRedeem" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter pointsToRedeem column" HeaderText="Redeem" SortExpression="pointsToRedeem" UniqueName="pointsToRedeem" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateToBeAwarded" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter dateToBeAwarded column" HeaderText="Award Date" SortExpression="dateToBeAwarded" UniqueName="dateToBeAwarded" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>

   <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="isActivated" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter isActivated column" HeaderText="Activated" SortExpression="isActivated" UniqueName="isActivated" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
 <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="isProcessed" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter isProcessed column" HeaderText="Processed" SortExpression="isProcessed" UniqueName="isProcessed" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
   <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="approvedDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter approvedDate column" HeaderText="Date Approved" SortExpression="approvedDate" UniqueName="approvedDate" ReadOnly="True">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
 <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="approved" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter approved column" HeaderText="Approved" SortExpression="approved" UniqueName="approved" ReadOnly="True">
   </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>

  </Columns>
</MasterTableView>

<FilterMenu RenderMode="Auto"></FilterMenu>

<HeaderContextMenu RenderMode="Auto"></HeaderContextMenu>

</telerik:RadGrid>
```

As you see above in the entity data source I have asked it to include player which is setup as a foreign key in edmx Which you can see here

[image]

**My Main Questions** are what do i need to put in my entity data source strings to be able to display player.Name and what should my other values be in this line.

** What I have tried **

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="playerName" FilterControlAltText="Filter playerName column" HeaderText="Player Name" SortExpression="playerName" UniqueName="playerName" ReadOnly="True">
```

**I tried the following as well but got the bellow error**

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="entPoints" Include="player" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=soccerEntities" DefaultContainerName="soccerEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="player_points" Select="it.[id], it.[playerId], it.[points], it.[pointsToRedeem], it.[dateToBeAwarded], it.[approvedBy], it.[approved], it.[authCreatedDate], it.[modifiedDate], it.[modifiedBy], it.[isActivated], it.[authUserName], it.[siteId], it.[sentApproveEmail], it.[approvedDate], it.[playerNumber], it.[playerName], it.[teamId], it.[isProcessed], it.[sentEmailToAdmin], it.[sentEmailToUser]"></asp:EntityDataSource>
```

and I used a templated column in my grid

```
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("player.Name") %>' />

        </ItemTemplate>

    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

> Error : The result type of the query is neither an EntityType nor a CollectionType with an entity element type. An Include path can only be specified for a query with one of these result types.